# Track down a textmate snippet by keybinding

Tags: textmate

I'm trying to use a snippet from an installed bundle that has the keybinding command+shift+a. The problem is that it's being overridden by some other snippet. How do I track down that snippet and remove it's keybinding so I can use the one I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press ⌘⌃T to show the Select Bundle Item window, then click on the magnifying glass and switch the field to "Key equivalent". Now type the keyboard shortcut.